# Android has Services interface, what about BlackBerry 10 cascades

Tags: service, background, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

In Android mobile application development we have ***Services*** interface for perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. What is the similar substitute for ***BlackBerry 10 Cascades*** development for long-running operations in the background?

Comment: Any updates on this? Is it possible to port Android application having one Service to BlackBerry 10.2?

Comment: Yes, this needs "BB10 Headless App" feature. It is introduced in the 10.2 SDK, which has been released as gold 14.08.2013. You'll need a 10.2 OS too (which has not been deployed yet, [except test](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html), stripped down versions) to use them.

Comment: And once you have converted the Android app to BlackBerry app (apk2bar) you add _sys_headless_nostop in the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, BB10 does not allow backgrounded services, although this is supposed to be supported in 10.2.

Comment: See the roadmap here: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/ - planed for August.